# React router 4 `Link` component only changing the url and not updating the route

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-v4, react-router-dom

I'm having trouble with react-router-dom `Link` component only changing the URL and not updating the route.

It works fine linking from `/courses -> /courses/<course-slug>`
and then `/courses/<course-slug> -> /lessons/<lesson-slug>`

However it the I'm having problems linking to other lessons e.g. from `/lessons/<lesson-slug> -> /lessons/<different-lesson-slug>`

It seems like it only updates the `LessonsList` component and updates the URL but doesn't update the route / content or parent `Lesson`.

I've made sure to pass match, location props down to the component incase it had anything to do with update blocking - https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/guides/dealing-with-update-blocking but it still doesn't seem to work.

I can't see where I'm going wrong, and it should be relatively simple.

Does it have anything to do with how I've set up my routes or the routes having the same?

Here's my dependencies and code, any point in the right direction would be appreciated.

```
"dependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.16.2",
    "prop-types": "^15.5.10",
    "react": "^15.6.1",
    "react-dom": "^15.6.1",
    "react-router-dom": "^4.1.2"
 }
```

index.js

```
    import css from '../css/index.scss';
    import React from 'react';
    import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
    import { BrowserRouter as Router } from 'react-router-dom';
    import App from './components/App';

    ReactDOM.render(
      <Router>
        <App />
      </Router>
    , document.getElementById('app'));
```

App/index.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Header from '../Header';
import Main from '../Main';
import Footer from '../Footer';

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return(
      <div>
        <Header />
        <Main />
        <Footer />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Main/index.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Route, Link, Switch } from 'react-router-dom';
import Home from '../Home';
import Courses from '../Courses';
import Course from '../Course';
import Lessons from '../Lessons';
import Lesson from '../Lesson';

class Main extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  render() {
    return(
      <div className="main">
        <Switch>
          <Route exact path="/" component={Home}/>
          <Route path="/courses/:course" component={Course}/>
          <Route exact path="/courses" component={Courses}/>
          <Route path="/lessons/:lesson" component={Lesson}/>
          <Route exact path="/lessons" component={Lessons}/>
          <Route render={ () => (
            <div>Not Found 404</div>
          )}/>
        </Switch>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Main;
```

Lessons/index.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import api from '../../utils/api';
import LessonsList from '../LessonsList';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';

class Lessons extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      lessons: null
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    api.getAllLessons()
      .then((lessons) => {
        this.setState({
          lessons: lessons
        });
      });
  }

  render() {
    return(
      <div className="lessons">
        {!this.state.lessons ?
          <div>Loading...</div>
          :
          <div>
            <LessonsList 
              lessons={this.state.lessons}
              {...this.props}
            />
          </div>
        }
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Lessons;
```

Lesson/index.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import api from '../../utils/api';
import LessonsList from '../LessonsList';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';

class Lesson extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      lesson: null
    }
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    api.getLesson(this.props.match.params.lesson)
      .then((lesson) => {
        this.setState({
          lesson: lesson[0]
        });
      });
  }

  render() {
    return(
      <div className="lesson">
        {!this.state.lesson ?
          <div>Loading...</div>
          :
          <div>
            <h3>Course title: {this.state.lesson.course.title}</h3>
            <h1>Lesson: {this.state.lesson.title}</h1>
            <h2>Other lessons from this course</h2>
            <LessonsList
              lessons={this.state.lesson.lessons}
              {...this.props}
            />
          </div>
        }
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Lesson;
```

LessonsList/index.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';

function LessonsList(props) {
  return(
    <ul>
      {props.lessons.map((lesson) => {
        return(
          <li key={lesson.id}>         
            <Link to={`/lessons/${lesson.slug}`}>{lesson.title}</Link>
          </li>
        );
      })}
    </ul>
  );
}

LessonsList.propTypes = {
  lessons: PropTypes.array.isRequired
}

export default LessonsList;
```

**UPDATE:**

Here's the updated Component with `componentWillReceiveProps`

Lesson/index.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import api from '../../utils/api';
import LessonsList from '../LessonsList';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';

class Lesson extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      lesson: null
    }
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    api.getLesson(this.props.match.params.lesson)
      .then((lesson) => {
        this.setState({
          lesson: lesson[0]
        });
      });
  }

  componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    if(this.props.match.params.lesson !== nextProps.match.params.lesson) {
      api.getLesson(nextProps.match.params.lesson)
        .then((lesson) => {
            this.setState({
            lesson: lesson[0]
          });
        });
    }
  }

  render() {
    return(
      <div className="lesson">
        {!this.state.lesson ?
          <div>Loading...</div>
          :
          <div>
            <h3>Course title: {this.state.lesson.course.title}</h3>
            <h1>Lesson: {this.state.lesson.title}</h1>
            <h2>Other lessons from this course</h2>
            <LessonsList
              lessons={this.state.lesson.lessons}
              {...this.props}
            />
          </div>
        }
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Lesson;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `<Lesson />` component only sets the lesson during the `componentDidMount` lifecycle hook. If you're on a lesson and you change the slug, it does not cause the component to remount. You can use the `componentWillReceiveProps` lifecycle hook to accomplish what you're after.

```
componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    api.getLesson(nextProps.match.params.lesson)
        .then((lesson) => {
            this.setState({
            lesson: lesson[0]
        });
    });
}
```

Comment: This was the point in the right direction I needed! Thank you. Although I needed to pass the updated props to get the new slug.

Answer (score 0):

This issue with componentDidMount event. It's not fired when you change Lesson. So you should use componentDidUpdate to change a lesson.

```
  componentDidUpdate() {
    if (this.props.match.params.lesson !== this.state.lesson.slug)
     api.getLesson(this.props.match.params.lesson)
          .then((lesson) => {
            this.setState({
              lesson: lesson[0]
            });
          });
        }
      }
```

Comment: Why would you wait until after the update to use setState?

Comment: We can use componentWillReceiveProps too, it's not critical, data will be passed to state after update anyway

Comment: Using the componentDidUpdate hook will cause an extraneous render. It's not that this is the worst thing in the world, it's just not needed.

Comment: we have async request, so component will render twice in all cases. First after prop change and the second after response and set new state.